# Can't push in array in recursive function in Ruby / RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, hash, yaml

I want to manipulate the following locales .yml file in Ruby On Rails:

`fr:
  back: Retour
  signup: Inscription
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Créer votre %{model}"
  hello: 
    world: "Bonjour le monde"`

So I parse it in my controller like :

`@yml_hash = YAML.load_file("config/locales/en.yml")`

Then I process it with the following helper in my html.erb file :

```
module TranslationHelper

    def render_hash(hash)
        return ihash(hash)
    end

    def ihash(h, key = [], result = [])
        h.each_pair do |k,v|
            if v.is_a?(Hash)
                key << k
                ihash(v, key, result)
            else
                result << {full_key: key, key: k, value: v}
            end
        end
        result
    end

end
```

And it's return the output:

```
[{:full_key=>["fr", "helpers", "submit", "hello"], :key=>"back",
  :value=>"Retour"},
 {:full_key=>["fr", "helpers", "submit", "hello"], :key=>"signup",
  :value=>"Inscription"},
 {:full_key=>["fr", "helpers", "submit", "hello"], :key=>"create",
  :value=>"Créer votre %{model}"},
 {:full_key=>["fr", "helpers", "submit", "hello"], :key=>"world",
  :value=>"Bonjour le monde"}]
```

---

But actually my goal is to have the full key of a value in the hash like this:

```
[{:full_key=>["fr"], :key=>"back", :value=>"Retour"},
 {:full_key=>["fr"], :key=>"signup", :value=>"Inscription"},
 {:full_key=>["fr", "helpers", "submit"], :key=>"create", :value=>"Créer votre %{model}"},
 {:full_key=>["fr", "hello"], :key=>"world", :value=>"Bonjour le monde"}]
```

Is there any way to handle hash in my function in order to have those kind of results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `clone` method to make new array because refer to same array object (`key << k`)

Correct:

```
def ihash(h, key = [], result = [])
  h.each_pair do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      new_key = key.clone
      new_key << k
      ihash(v, new_key, result)
    else
      result << {full_key: key, key: k, value: v}
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Happy coding!